# English grammar so vs such

Tags: grammar

I was doing test. It says the following sentence is correct:

The aviation influenza is so deadly a disease all countries are trying to find a cure for it.

But as we know, we use such+ adjective+ noun.....and so + adjective without noun....

So, ı was confused. Could you comment on this please.

Comment: Welcome to ELL :-). Two things: 1) I suspect that "aviation" influenza should be **avian** influenza (the one we catch from birds - avis, avis *lat.* - bird). If it's not a typo it makes me question the validity of the source of the test. 2) You are citing some sort of a rule - if you have a source for that rule and could edit your question to include it, that would be great :-). Aside from the "wrong" sort of influenza the sentence sounds fine to me. This might have to do something with the position of the article; consider: *such a deadly disease*, *so deadly a disease*...